# Why is Szymborska's "Tarsier" sometimes written (in translation) with simplistic grammar?

Tags: poetry, translation, style, polish-language, wislawa-szymborska

Szymborska's poem "Tarsier" ("Tarsjusz" in the original Polish) has been [translated](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25777690?seq=11#metadata_info_tab_contents), in a version that says "Translations and Comments by Magnus J. Krynski and Robert A. Maguire", as follows:

> I tarsier, son of tarsier,
> grandson of tarsier and great-grandson,
> [...]
> I tarsier,
> know how important it is to be tarsier.

[Another](https://tubagbohol.mikeligalig.com/poetry/tarsier-by-wislawa-szymborska/) English translation (I don't know who was the translator here) uses less idiosyncratic grammar:

> I am a tarsier and a tarsier's son,
> the grandson and great-grandson of tarsiers,
> [...]
> I, a tarsier,
> know well how essential it is to be a tarsier.

Which of these translations better captures the style of the original Polish poem? Did Szymborska write in an "I tarsier" style of grammar, perhaps indicating a simple childish creature, or in fully correct grammatical sentences?

It should be noted that Polish, like many/all Slavic languages, has no articles, no equivalent words for "a" and "the". When translating from Polish to English, the choice of where to put articles may sometimes be a stylistic one. But is it the translators putting their own style into "I tarsier", or trying to capture Szymborska's original style?

Comment: FWIW, I asked a Russian friend if *внук Тарсия и правнук* (Google translation to *wnuk tar­sju­sza i pra­wnuk*) is grammatical in Russian, and it isn't (it should be: *внук Тарсия и правнук Тарсия*), so it can hint about Polish (i.e., if it's not grammatical, the first translation is closer to the original). Maybe you should just ask about the grammar on e.g SE Linguistics.

Comment: @HeyJude In Russian, there's no word for *am/is/are* as well as no word for *a/an/the*. Saying "I am a tarsier" in Russian would be just two words, like "I tarsier". But it's not quite like that in Polish: there's a single word *jestem* but it encodes both words in "I am". (I don't speak either language fully, but I know a little about them both.) It's not a purely grammatical/linguistic question, as I'm also interested in the point of the stylistic choice made by the author and/or translator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think the first translation you mention is more accurate.** Still, omitting comma in first line and adding in last would be more accurate, and here is why:

In original it's

> Ja tarsjusz syn tarsjusza,
> wnuk tarsjusza i prawnuk,
> [...]
> Ja tarsjusz
> wiem, jak bardzo trzeba być tarsjuszem.

In the first row it's not "Ja jestem tarsjusz", or "Ja jestem tarsjuszem", "Jestem tarsjusz", ''Jestem tarsjuszem'' - while "Ja" (I) can be omitted, omitting "jestem" (am) would normally go with comma (Ja, tarsjusz = I, tarsier). So, it's rather a matter of punctuation then grammar. Why is it like that? I don't think it's conveying any childishness, rather it makes the line a sort of "not a list". Together with second line it conveys certain... timelessness, or universality, which should also be translated. That's why there should be no articles in translation - it's not about a tarsier, or the tarsier - not any particular, like [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246032/man-or-a-the-man). It also preserves highly condensed from of these lines.